# deleting related entities in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, one-to-many

I have this domain:

```
public class Phone {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

I load a `Person` and clear its `Phones`. But the operation cause an error:

```
// actually loads person from repository...
var person = _personRepository.Include(p => p.Phones).Where(p => p.Id == 1).First();
person.Phones.Clear();
_personRepository.Update(person);
```

Above you can see the simpled logic of loading a `Person` and clearing its `Phones`. But this error occurs:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

Actually I want to clear all of `Person.Phones` and add some new items. But I want to clearing them in one query, not delete them one by one.

Have you any idea? Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you google it? There are plenty of questions and answers about this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set you foreign key to nullable. Is the FK listed as int or int?.

Comment: @Eranga I googled it. There is some ways that iterate the `Phones` and delete them one by one! But in `NH` we can do this very simple -as shown I above. I'm asking a same way in `EF`.

Comment: @Slump bad idea. The `Phone` entity is a `Dependent Entity`. If set its `Id` to `null` it will be stored in db with out any associated `Person`. So I have to delete them one by one -or at least in a separate query such as a sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generate set based SQL in EF. So there's no way in EF to generate a single SQL statement that deletes all `Phone` records given a `Person.Id`.

You can write the SQL yourself and pass it to either [ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx) or [DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) depending on your model.

Comment: OK thanks it seems it's the only possible way. I did it before. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var phone in person.Phones)
{
   context.DeleteObject(phone);
}
person.Phones.Clear();
```

may help.